# Lines not drawing to picture box every time

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, picturebox, pen

When my code runs only about 1/3 of the time it will actually draw properly, the rest it will just not draw some of the lines.

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        Graphics graphics = MainFrm.HangmanImage.CreateGraphics();
        switch (NoOfGuesses)
        {
            case 1://Bottom left leg
                graphics.DrawLine(pen, 15, 60, 40, 60);
                break;
            case 2://Bottom right leg
                graphics.DrawLine(pen, 40, 60, 55, 60);
                break;
            case 3://Middle stock
                graphics.DrawLine(pen, 34, 20, 34, 60);
                break;
            case 4: //Top line
                graphics.DrawLine(pen, 34, 20, 55, 20);
                break;
            case 5: //Rope
                graphics.DrawLine(pen, 55, 20, 55, 25);
                break;
            case 6: //Head
                graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, (new Rectangle { X=52, Y=25, Height=5, Width=5 }));
                break;
            case 7: //Body
                graphics.DrawLine(pen, 55, 30, 55, 35);
                break;
        }
        pen.Dispose();
        graphics.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to be sure, however, I would first make sure that your variable 'NoOfGuesses' is always a value between 1-7, a value of 0 or 8 will end up doing nothing.  Second, I would add a 'default' case in case your 'NoOfGuesses' is out of that range for any reason and have it also draw a line.

Comment: Or have it print some warning message on `default`. A line doesn't convey as much information, and could blend into the application.

Comment: NoOfGuesses is always in the range of this. Plus if it was an error like that, then it wouldn't draw the line some of the time and not the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by running this code on the form's paint event, it seems it was forgetting about it whenever it redrew the form.